# Retrieve image in django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to make a gallery website but I cannot seem to retrieve the images to display in the html. I'm trying to retrieve images from the database based on a `filter_type` which has value as image.

So far I have this:

In `views.py`

```
def gallery(request):
    img = Upload.objects.filter(file_type='image')
    return render(request,'gallery.html',{"img":img})
```

and in `html`:

```
{% for n in img %}
        <img src="{{ n.img}}" />
{% endfor %}
```

My `models.py` is as follow:

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/image',default='')
    text_field = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=[('image', 'image'), ('video', 'video'), ('other', 'other')])
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Files Manager"
```

I've also set up `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT`. From the Admin I can upload images and they are ok.

my `MEDIA_URL`:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static','media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

When I view the html the `src` path is empty.

Comment: Have you tried `<img src="{{ n.img.url}}" />` ? Instead of `<img src="{{ n.img}}" />`.

Comment: yes still empty. If there is more infomratio needed about the project i can post more. It's still empty.

Comment: Can you do `print(img)` (if you're using python3, or `print img` for python2) after `img = Upload.objects.filter(file_type='image')` and paste here what you see in django console log?

Comment: [<Upload: Upload object>] <- this is what print(img) comes up in console.
[20/Sep/2015 01:31:03] "GET /gallery/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1884'

Comment: Added in the body of the question to the end. As a question should i add MEDIA_ULR to the returned dicitonary or something like that???

Comment: Try `image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image',default='')` instead of `image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/image',default='')`.

Comment: You should have something like this in your `urls.py` (didn't understand your question but I think you were referring to this):

`if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.static',
        (r'media/(?P<path>.*)', 'serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )`

Comment: Check `Serving files uploaded by a user during development` section in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/).

Comment: Thanks i solved the problem!

Comment: Want to share the issue? And maybe post an answer so that others can solve it too? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved.

The main reason the images where not displayed in my html was because the path was wrong. I should have took it from my media_url + name of the file, ,since media_url was not added, there was no path to be displayd correctly. The correct way it was:
for `VIEWS.py :`

```
def gallery(request):
    img = Upload.objects.filter(file_type='image')
    return render(request,'gallery.html',{"img":img, 'media_url':settings.MEDIA_URL})
```

and for `html`:

```
{% for i in img %}
                <img src="{{media_url}}{{ i.image }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Hopefuly this answers somebody's question or if not at least I can go on now.:) thanks all for support.

Answer (score 0):

Save your image in static/upload/image folder in pycharm. And then use 
`<img src="../../static/upload/Image-name"/>` in your html page